# Question Limit exceeded but I haven't asked any!

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting

I've literally just signed up to Stack Overflow and I tried asking my first question, unfortunately I keep getting this error message

> You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period.

Having just signed up, I haven't asked any questions yet, and definitely not 50!

I am currently living in the halls at my university, could this be causing the problem?
And if so, is there anyway I can get around this as I really need some help :(

Comment: Many of the rate limits are IP Address based, so if everyone in your dorm shares an IP address, then that is why you are getting blocked.  I don't think there is a way around it, but someone else might have an idea.

Comment: You could post from a university computer, or if you have a laptop use some nearby wifi.

Answer (score 18):

There are something like 134 different accounts sharing the same IP as you. In order to prevent abuse, this limit is imposed on both an account *and* IP-level - otherwise, prolific askers would just create new accounts to get around it.

Try logging on as close to 0:00 UTC as possible - if you're the first one to get in, you'll be able to post.

Also, find the guy who posted 15 questions in the past 30 days and send him on a really long, time-consuming errand. Give him a ring that needs to be destroyed in the fires of Mount Doom if need-be.

You may also find that some limits are raised a bit if you're able to contribute useful answers or edits...

Comment: One does not simply wal... ehh... nevermind!

Comment: I apologize, but I don't think this is an appropriate solution to the problem. A legitimate user is being stopped, and the response is... try and work around it in one of the most inconvenient ways possible? Hmmmm.....

Comment: I don't really have a *more* convenient solution, @Emracool (post from your phone maybe?) This is one of the downsides of doing IP-level blocking - and if you think this is bad, we've had to block major ISPs in the past due to a few subscribers pushing vast amounts of spam our way. It sucks that a few bad apples can ruin things for others this way, but, them's the breaks.